# Create a matrix from the dataframe of all permutations

Tags: python, numpy, dataframe, matrix

I have a dataframe for all possible combinations of 2 stations in Caltrain and fare for the trip between them. I want to make a matrix of values but cannot understand how. Data looks like that:

```
+=========================+=========================+========+
|       SOURCE_STN        |        DEST_STN         | RC1($) |
+=========================+=========================+========+
| 22nd Street             | Atherton                |   8.25 |
+-------------------------+-------------------------+--------+
| 22nd Street             | Redwood City            |      6 |
+-------------------------+-------------------------+--------+
| 22nd Street             | Millbrae Transit Center |      6 |
+-------------------------+-------------------------+--------+
| 22nd Street             | Stanford                |   8.25 |
+-------------------------+-------------------------+--------+
| 22nd Street             | Santa Clara             |   10.5 |
+-------------------------+-------------------------+--------+
| 22nd Street             | California Ave.         |   8.25 |
+-------------------------+-------------------------+--------+
| 22nd Street             | Tamien                  |   10.5 |
+-------------------------+-------------------------+--------+
| 22nd Street             | Lawrence                |   10.5 |
+-------------------------+-------------------------+--------+
| 22nd Street             | San Antonio             |   8.25 |
+-------------------------+-------------------------+--------+
| 22nd Street             | Burlingame              |      6 |
+-------------------------+-------------------------+--------+
| 22nd Street             | San Mateo               |      6 |
+-------------------------+-------------------------+--------+
| 22nd Street             | Hayward Park            |      6 |
+-------------------------+-------------------------+--------+
| 22nd Street             | Blossom Hill            |  12.75 |
+-------------------------+-------------------------+--------+
| 22nd Street             | South San Francisco     |   3.75 |
+-------------------------+-------------------------+--------+
| 22nd Street             | San Carlos              |      6 |
+-------------------------+-------------------------+--------+
| 22nd Street             | San Jose Diridon        |   10.5 |
+-------------------------+-------------------------+--------+
| 22nd Street             | Gilroy                  |     15 |
+-------------------------+-------------------------+--------+
| 22nd Street             | College Park            |   10.5 |
+-------------------------+-------------------------+--------+
| 22nd Street             | Menlo Park              |   8.25 |
+-------------------------+-------------------------+--------+
| 22nd Street             | Palo Alto               |   8.25 |
+-------------------------+-------------------------+--------+
| 22nd Street             | Belmont                 |      6 |
+-------------------------+-------------------------+--------+
| 22nd Street             | Menlo Park              |   8.25 |
+-------------------------+-------------------------+--------+
| 22nd Street             | Broadway                |      6 |
+-------------------------+-------------------------+--------+
| 22nd Street             | Sunnyvale               |   8.25 |
+-------------------------+-------------------------+--------+
| 22nd Street             | San Martin              |     15 |
+-------------------------+-------------------------+--------+
| 22nd Street             | Morgan Hill             |     15 |
+-------------------------+-------------------------+--------+
| 22nd Street             | Hillsdale               |      6 |
+-------------------------+-------------------------+--------+
| 22nd Street             | Capitol                 |  12.75 |
+-------------------------+-------------------------+--------+
| 22nd Street             | Bayshore                |   3.75 |
+-------------------------+-------------------------+--------+
| 22nd Street             | Mountain View           |   8.25 |
+-------------------------+-------------------------+--------+
| 22nd Street             | San Francisco           |   3.75 |
+-------------------------+-------------------------+--------+
| Atherton                | Redwood City            |      6 |
+-------------------------+-------------------------+--------+
| Atherton                | Millbrae Transit Center |      6 |
+-------------------------+-------------------------+--------+
| Atherton                | Stanford                |   8.25 |
+-------------------------+-------------------------+--------+
| Atherton                | Santa Clara             |   10.5 |
+-------------------------+-------------------------+--------+
| Atherton                | California Ave.         |   8.25 |
+-------------------------+-------------------------+--------+
| Atherton                | Tamien                  |   10.5 |
+-------------------------+-------------------------+--------+
| Atherton                | Lawrence                |   10.5 |
+-------------------------+-------------------------+--------+
| Atherton                | San Antonio             |   8.25 |
+-------------------------+-------------------------+--------+
| Atherton                | Burlingame              |      6 |
+-------------------------+-------------------------+--------+
| Atherton                | San Mateo               |      6 |
+-------------------------+-------------------------+--------+
| Atherton                | Hayward Park            |      6 |
+-------------------------+-------------------------+--------+
| Atherton                | Blossom Hill            |  12.75 |
+-------------------------+-------------------------+--------+
| Atherton                | South San Francisco     |   3.75 |
+-------------------------+-------------------------+--------+
| Atherton                | San Carlos              |      6 |
+-------------------------+-------------------------+--------+
| Atherton                | San Jose Diridon        |   10.5 |
+-------------------------+-------------------------+--------+
| Atherton                | Gilroy                  |     15 |
+-------------------------+-------------------------+--------+
| Atherton                | College Park            |   10.5 |
+-------------------------+-------------------------+--------+
| Atherton                | Menlo Park              |   8.25 |
+-------------------------+-------------------------+--------+
| Atherton                | Palo Alto               |   8.25 |
+-------------------------+-------------------------+--------+
| Atherton                | Menlo Park              |   8.25 |
+-------------------------+-------------------------+--------+
| Atherton                | 22nd Street             |   3.75 |
+-------------------------+-------------------------+--------+
| Atherton                | Broadway                |      6 |
+-------------------------+-------------------------+--------+
| Atherton                | Sunnyvale               |   8.25 |
+-------------------------+-------------------------+--------+
| Atherton                | San Martin              |     15 |
+-------------------------+-------------------------+--------+
| Atherton                | Belmont                 |      6 |
+-------------------------+-------------------------+--------+
| Atherton                | Morgan Hill             |     15 |
+-------------------------+-------------------------+--------+
| Atherton                | Hillsdale               |      6 |
+-------------------------+-------------------------+--------+
| Atherton                | Capitol                 |  12.75 |
+-------------------------+-------------------------+--------+
| Atherton                | Bayshore                |   3.75 |
+-------------------------+-------------------------+--------+
| Atherton                | Mountain View           |   8.25 |
+-------------------------+-------------------------+--------+
| Atherton                | San Francisco           |   3.75 |
+-------------------------+-------------------------+--------+
| Bayshore                | Atherton                |   8.25 |
+-------------------------+-------------------------+--------+
| Bayshore                | Redwood City            |      6 |
+-------------------------+-------------------------+--------+
| Bayshore                | Millbrae Transit Center |      6 |
+-------------------------+-------------------------+--------+
| Bayshore                | Stanford                |   8.25 |
+-------------------------+-------------------------+--------+
| Bayshore                | Santa Clara             |   10.5 |
+-------------------------+-------------------------+--------+
| Bayshore                | Menlo Park              |   8.25 |
+-------------------------+-------------------------+--------+
| Bayshore                | 22nd Street             |   3.75 |
+-------------------------+-------------------------+--------+
| Bayshore                | Broadway                |      6 |
+-------------------------+-------------------------+--------+
| Bayshore                | Sunnyvale               |   8.25 |
+-------------------------+-------------------------+--------+
| Bayshore                | San Martin              |     15 |
+-------------------------+-------------------------+--------+
| Bayshore                | California Ave.         |   8.25 |
+-------------------------+-------------------------+--------+
| Bayshore                | Tamien                  |   10.5 |
+-------------------------+-------------------------+--------+
| Bayshore                | Lawrence                |   10.5 |
+-------------------------+-------------------------+--------+
| Bayshore                | San Antonio             |   8.25 |
+-------------------------+-------------------------+--------+
| Bayshore                | Burlingame              |      6 |
+-------------------------+-------------------------+--------+
| Bayshore                | San Mateo               |      6 |
+-------------------------+-------------------------+--------+
| Bayshore                | Hayward Park            |      6 |
+-------------------------+-------------------------+--------+
| Bayshore                | Blossom Hill            |  12.75 |
+-------------------------+-------------------------+--------+
| Bayshore                | South San Francisco     |   3.75 |
+-------------------------+-------------------------+--------+
| Bayshore                | San Carlos              |      6 |
+-------------------------+-------------------------+--------+
| Bayshore                | San Jose Diridon        |   10.5 |
+-------------------------+-------------------------+--------+
| Bayshore                | Gilroy                  |     15 |
+-------------------------+-------------------------+--------+
| Bayshore                | College Park            |   10.5 |
+-------------------------+-------------------------+--------+
| Bayshore                | Menlo Park              |   8.25 |
+-------------------------+-------------------------+--------+
| Bayshore                | Palo Alto               |   8.25 |
+-------------------------+-------------------------+--------+
| Bayshore                | Belmont                 |      6 |
+-------------------------+-------------------------+--------+
| Bayshore                | Morgan Hill             |     15 |
+-------------------------+-------------------------+--------+
| Bayshore                | Hillsdale               |      6 |
+-------------------------+-------------------------+--------+
| Bayshore                | Capitol                 |  12.75 |
+-------------------------+-------------------------+--------+
| Bayshore                | Mountain View           |   8.25 |
+-------------------------+-------------------------+--------+
| Bayshore                | San Francisco           |   3.75 |
+-------------------------+-------------------------+--------+
| Belmont                 | Atherton                |   8.25 |
+-------------------------+-------------------------+--------+
| Belmont                 | Redwood City            |      6 |
+-------------------------+-------------------------+--------+
| Belmont                 | Millbrae Transit Center |      6 |
+-------------------------+-------------------------+--------+
| Belmont                 | Stanford                |   8.25 |
+-------------------------+-------------------------+--------+
| Belmont                 | Santa Clara             |   10.5 |
+-------------------------+-------------------------+--------+
| Belmont                 | Menlo Park              |   8.25 |
+-------------------------+-------------------------+--------+
| Belmont                 | 22nd Street             |   3.75 |
+-------------------------+-------------------------+--------+
| Belmont                 | Broadway                |      6 |
+-------------------------+-------------------------+--------+
| Belmont                 | Sunnyvale               |   8.25 |
+-------------------------+-------------------------+--------+
| Belmont                 | San Martin              |     15 |
+-------------------------+-------------------------+--------+
| Belmont                 | California Ave.         |   8.25 |
+-------------------------+-------------------------+--------+
| Belmont                 | Tamien                  |   10.5 |
+-------------------------+-------------------------+--------+
| Belmont                 | Lawrence                |   10.5 |
+-------------------------+-------------------------+--------+
| Belmont                 | San Antonio             |   8.25 |
+-------------------------+-------------------------+--------+
| Belmont                 | Burlingame              |      6 |
+-------------------------+-------------------------+--------+
| Belmont                 | San Mateo               |      6 |
+-------------------------+-------------------------+--------+
| Belmont                 | Hayward Park            |      6 |
+-------------------------+-------------------------+--------+
| Belmont                 | Blossom Hill            |  12.75 |
+-------------------------+-------------------------+--------+
| Belmont                 | South San Francisco     |   3.75 |
+-------------------------+-------------------------+--------+
| Belmont                 | San Carlos              |      6 |
+-------------------------+-------------------------+--------+
| Belmont                 | San Jose Diridon        |   10.5 |
+-------------------------+-------------------------+--------+
| Belmont                 | Gilroy                  |     15 |
+-------------------------+-------------------------+--------+
| Belmont                 | College Park            |   10.5 |
+-------------------------+-------------------------+--------+
| Belmont                 | Menlo Park              |   8.25 |
+-------------------------+-------------------------+--------+
| Belmont                 | Palo Alto               |   8.25 |
+-------------------------+-------------------------+--------+
| Belmont                 | Morgan Hill             |     15 |
+-------------------------+-------------------------+--------+
| Belmont                 | Hillsdale               |      6 |
+-------------------------+-------------------------+--------+
| Belmont                 | Capitol                 |  12.75 |
+-------------------------+-------------------------+--------+
| Belmont                 | Bayshore                |   3.75 |
+-------------------------+-------------------------+--------+
| Belmont                 | Mountain View           |   8.25 |
+-------------------------+-------------------------+--------+
| Belmont                 | San Francisco           |   3.75 |
+-------------------------+-------------------------+--------+
| Blossom Hill            | Atherton                |   8.25 |
+-------------------------+-------------------------+--------+
| Blossom Hill            | Redwood City            |      6 |
+-------------------------+-------------------------+--------+
| Blossom Hill            | Millbrae Transit Center |      6 |
+-------------------------+-------------------------+--------+
| Blossom Hill            | Stanford                |   8.25 |
+-------------------------+-------------------------+--------+
| Blossom Hill            | Santa Clara             |   10.5 |
+-------------------------+-------------------------+--------+
| Blossom Hill            | Menlo Park              |   8.25 |
+-------------------------+-------------------------+--------+
| Blossom Hill            | 22nd Street             |   3.75 |
+-------------------------+-------------------------+--------+
| Blossom Hill            | Broadway                |      6 |
+-------------------------+-------------------------+--------+
| Blossom Hill            | Sunnyvale               |   8.25 |
+-------------------------+-------------------------+--------+
| Blossom Hill            | San Martin              |     15 |
+-------------------------+-------------------------+--------+
| Blossom Hill            | California Ave.         |   8.25 |
+-------------------------+-------------------------+--------+
| Blossom Hill            | Tamien                  |   10.5 |
+-------------------------+-------------------------+--------+
| Blossom Hill            | Lawrence                |   10.5 |
+-------------------------+-------------------------+--------+
| Blossom Hill            | San Antonio             |   8.25 |
+-------------------------+-------------------------+--------+
| Blossom Hill            | Burlingame              |      6 |
+-------------------------+-------------------------+--------+
| Blossom Hill            | San Mateo               |      6 |
+-------------------------+-------------------------+--------+
| Blossom Hill            | Hayward Park            |      6 |
+-------------------------+-------------------------+--------+
| Blossom Hill            | South San Francisco     |   3.75 |
+-------------------------+-------------------------+--------+
| Blossom Hill            | San Carlos              |      6 |
+-------------------------+-------------------------+--------+
| Blossom Hill            | San Jose Diridon        |   10.5 |
+-------------------------+-------------------------+--------+
| Blossom Hill            | Gilroy                  |     15 |
+-------------------------+-------------------------+--------+
| Blossom Hill            | College Park            |   10.5 |
+-------------------------+-------------------------+--------+
| Blossom Hill            | Menlo Park              |   8.25 |
+-------------------------+-------------------------+--------+
| Blossom Hill            | Palo Alto               |   8.25 |
+-------------------------+-------------------------+--------+
| Blossom Hill            | Belmont                 |      6 |
+-------------------------+-------------------------+--------+
| Blossom Hill            | Morgan Hill             |     15 |
+-------------------------+-------------------------+--------+
| Blossom Hill            | Hillsdale               |      6 |
+-------------------------+-------------------------+--------+
| Blossom Hill            | Capitol                 |  12.75 |
+-------------------------+-------------------------+--------+
| Blossom Hill            | Bayshore                |   3.75 |
+-------------------------+-------------------------+--------+
| Blossom Hill            | Mountain View           |   8.25 |
+-------------------------+-------------------------+--------+
| Blossom Hill            | San Francisco           |   3.75 |
+-------------------------+-------------------------+--------+
| Broadway                | Atherton                |   8.25 |
+-------------------------+-------------------------+--------+
| Broadway                | Redwood City            |      6 |
+-------------------------+-------------------------+--------+
| Broadway                | Millbrae Transit Center |      6 |
+-------------------------+-------------------------+--------+
| Broadway                | Stanford                |   8.25 |
+-------------------------+-------------------------+--------+
| Broadway                | Santa Clara             |   10.5 |
+-------------------------+-------------------------+--------+
| Broadway                | Menlo Park              |   8.25 |
+-------------------------+-------------------------+--------+
| Broadway                | 22nd Street             |   3.75 |
+-------------------------+-------------------------+--------+
| Broadway                | Sunnyvale               |   8.25 |
+-------------------------+-------------------------+--------+
| Broadway                | San Martin              |     15 |
+-------------------------+-------------------------+--------+
| Broadway                | California Ave.         |   8.25 |
+-------------------------+-------------------------+--------+
| Broadway                | Tamien                  |   10.5 |
+-------------------------+-------------------------+--------+
| Broadway                | Lawrence                |   10.5 |
+-------------------------+-------------------------+--------+
| Broadway                | San Antonio             |   8.25 |
+-------------------------+-------------------------+--------+
| Broadway                | Burlingame              |      6 |
+-------------------------+-------------------------+--------+
| Broadway                | San Mateo               |      6 |
+-------------------------+-------------------------+--------+
| Broadway                | Hayward Park            |      6 |
+-------------------------+-------------------------+--------+
| Broadway                | Blossom Hill            |  12.75 |
+-------------------------+-------------------------+--------+
| Broadway                | South San Francisco     |   3.75 |
+-------------------------+-------------------------+--------+
| Broadway                | San Carlos              |      6 |
+-------------------------+-------------------------+--------+
| Broadway                | San Jose Diridon        |   10.5 |
+-------------------------+-------------------------+--------+
| Broadway                | Gilroy                  |     15 |
+-------------------------+-------------------------+--------+
| Broadway                | College Park            |   10.5 |
+-------------------------+-------------------------+--------+
| Broadway                | Menlo Park              |   8.25 |
+-------------------------+-------------------------+--------+
| Broadway                | Palo Alto               |   8.25 |
+-------------------------+-------------------------+--------+
| Broadway                | Morgan Hill             |     15 |
+-------------------------+-------------------------+--------+
| Broadway                | Belmont                 |      6 |
+-------------------------+-------------------------+--------+
| Broadway                | Hillsdale               |      6 |
+-------------------------+-------------------------+--------+
| Broadway                | Capitol                 |  12.75 |
+-------------------------+-------------------------+--------+
| Broadway                | Bayshore                |   3.75 |
+-------------------------+-------------------------+--------+
| Broadway                | Mountain View           |   8.25 |
+-------------------------+-------------------------+--------+
| Broadway                | San Francisco           |   3.75 |
+-------------------------+-------------------------+--------+
```

I tried to do something with pd.Dataframe(index = , columns =) but it does not work.
It must be like that:

```
+---------------+----------------+-----------+
|    station    |  San Francisco |  Broadway |
+---------------+----------------+-----------+
| San Francisco |  0             |  value    |
| Broadway      | value          |  0        |
+---------------+----------------+-----------+
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `df.pivot()`.

```
df.pivot(index='SOURCE_STN', columns='DEST_STN', values='RC1($)').fillna(0)
```

Edit: 
For dataframes with duplicates you need to use `df.pivot_table()` instead and specify an aggregation function in `aggfunc` parameter.

```
import numpy as np

df.pivot_table(index='SOURCE_STN', columns='DEST_STN', values='RC1($)', aggfunc=np.sum).fillna(0)
```

Comment: Oops, it does not work due to repeated stations in the source and dest as I have permutations.

Comment: It also does not work as for some of the stations combinations the fare is bigger than the biggest fare, and for other the fare is the same from one station to every station. Here is the link to the data: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1nXC3ZQM_JsPVtaCVm11Ipqh1tEd9hR4KHHLDGX4GMlc/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: @ZheniaMagic I don't understand: why are there duplicates? Is there anything else than going from station to itself?

Comment: @IgorRivin there are duplicates because I have 32 stations and the dataframe is basically all 993 permutations of them. So all possible pairs of the stations.

Comment: @ZheniaMagic But the `SOURCE_STN, DEST_STN` combination shouldn't have duplicates if it makes sense.

Comment: They have duplicates only for the reverse combinations such as San Francisco - Broadway and Broadway - San Francisco, with the same prices.

Comment: Is the expected output a matrix with the stations showing the same aggregated fare for source and destination regardless if they originally have different values? Lets say `22ndStreet -> Atherton = 12.0` and `Atherton -> 22ndStreet = 12.0` Is this the desired output?

Comment: @ZheniaMagic If you consider `San Francisco` and `Broadway`, `San Francisco -> Broadway` costs `$6` and `Broadway -> San Francisco` costs `$3.75`. I dont understand how they are duplicates if they have different prices unless you want to handle them by obtaining the price of the roundtrip between two stations of interest.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by using [pivot_table](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.pivot_table.html) in pandas.

```
data_frame.pivot_table('RC1($)', 'SOURCE_STN', 'DEST_STN').fillna(0)
```

**Explanation:**

The matrix you expect could be achieved by the following code as the permutations are still retained while also managing duplicates by obtaining the mean of duplicates.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

route_table = pd.read_csv("path_to_file.csv")

route_matrix = route_table.pivot_table('RC1($)', 'SOURCE_STN', 'DEST_STN', aggfunc=np.mean).fillna(0)
print(route_matrix)
```

**Output:**

```
DEST_STN                 22nd Street  Atherton  ...  Sunnyvale  Tamien
SOURCE_STN                                      ...                   
22nd Street                     0.00      8.25  ...       8.25    10.5
Atherton                        3.75      0.00  ...       8.25    10.5
Bayshore                        3.75      8.25  ...       8.25    10.5
Belmont                         3.75      8.25  ...       8.25    10.5
Blossom Hill                    3.75      8.25  ...       8.25    10.5
Broadway                        3.75      8.25  ...       8.25    10.5
Burlingame                      3.75      8.25  ...       8.25    10.5
California Ave.                 3.75      8.25  ...       8.25    10.5
Capitol                         3.75      8.25  ...       8.25    10.5
College Park                    3.75      8.25  ...       8.25    10.5
Gilroy                          3.75      8.25  ...       8.25    10.5
Hillsdale                       3.75      8.25  ...       8.25    10.5
```

---

**For a different perspective of the pivoted table to get a better understanding:**

**Alternate Code**

```
route_matrix = route_table.pivot_table('RC1($)', 'DEST_STN', 'SOURCE_STN', aggfunc=np.mean).fillna(0)
print(route_matrix)
```

**Output**

```
SOURCE_STN               22nd Street  Atherton  ...  Sunnyvale  Tamien
DEST_STN                                        ...                   
22nd Street                     0.00      3.75  ...       3.75    3.75
Atherton                        8.25      0.00  ...       8.25    8.25
Bayshore                        3.75      3.75  ...       3.75    3.75
Belmont                         6.00      6.00  ...       6.00    6.00
Blossom Hill                   12.75     12.75  ...      12.75   12.75
Broadway                        6.00      6.00  ...       6.00    6.00
Burlingame                      6.00      6.00  ...       6.00    6.00
California Ave.                 8.25      8.25  ...       8.25    8.25
Capitol                        12.75     12.75  ...      12.75   12.75
College Park                   10.50     10.50  ...      10.50   10.50
Gilroy                         15.00     15.00  ...      15.00   15.00
```

Comment: This answer also does not work due to repeated values.

Comment: the fare is the same from one station to every station after I implement your code...

Comment: @ZheniaMagic I think this answer should work fine for your case.